# What do you call an application that is not specifically tied to a DB structure

Tags: development-approach

I'm wondering what you call an applications that are not hard coded around any database structure?

Let me give a small example:

I have one application where the views, the controllers and the  model are tailored to the information and fields in the model, and thus the database.

I have a second (theoretical) application where the views and controllers are completely generic; I could change the fields in my database and make some minor adjustments to model classes and the application still works for editing/adding information.

I wouldn't try to create an application on either of these principles, but I'm wondering what you would label them as.

Comment: I'd call it "schema agnostic". But I would also call anything that is *completely* independent of the schema a framework, not an application.

Answer (score 2):

IMHO it's not really the application that is not tied to a DB structure but its architecture.

In that case, we'll speak about [Clean Architecture](http://blog.8thlight.com/uncle-bob/2011/11/22/Clean-Architecture.html).

As Uncle Bob says:

> a good architecture allows you to defer critical decisions like the
>   UI, frameworks, database, etc

Have a look at this pretty interesting [article](http://www.infoq.com/news/2013/07/architecture_intent_frameworks) as well, where it tells why:

> Architecture is About Intent, not Frameworks